# Check if any table fields are empty and return a HTML class in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to check if any or all of several database table fields are empty and if any of them are return a class in HTML (or Blade).

At the moment I do this:

```
<body class="app @if (Auth::user()->site_title == '' | Auth::user()->full_name == '' | Auth::user()->country == '' | Auth::user()->city == '') newuser @endif">
```

If the fields are empty it prompts a modal for the user to complete them.

Everything works great but I'm hoping for a cleaner way to do this as I need to use the same `@if` statement again to hide/show a modal accordingly at the bottom of the page.

Maybe return something from the User Model?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to extract the if conditions to a User method. Then you could "Auth::user()->isNew()" to shorten it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a method on your authentication model that returns a boolean.

Something like this:

```
public function isNew()
{
    $attributes = ['site_title', 'full_name', 'country', 'city'];
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (empty($this->$attribute)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in your view you simply check against this method:

```
 <body class="app @if (Auth::user()->isNew()) newuser @endif">
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I need, how do I assign the field names as attributes?

Comment: I did actually work that out, but I get this error `Call to undefined function App\Models\is_empty()` which I cant work out why. Also tried `isEmpty`

Comment: My bad, the correct function name is `empty`; mixed it up with `is_null`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this check in the controller, assign the result to a variable and pass it to the view. That way, you can easily use this variable any number of times in the view.

Another (perhaps cleaner) way, would be to do it in the User model. You could put this logic in a method User::isNewUser() and call that from your controller or directly from your view.